# Flask Models.py Foreign Key Proper Delcaration

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

This is my **first time** using flask's `sqlalchemy` and I have developed a `models.py` file, and created two tables in it:

```
class Tld(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Tld'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    uri =  Column(String(80))
    tmstmp = Column(DateTime())
    auth = Column(Boolean())

class PathOfTld(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PathOfTld'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tldpath = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    tmstmp = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False)
    Tld__FK = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey("Tld.id"), nullable=False)
```

Few questions:

1. is my `ForeignKey()` declaration valid?
2. How do I then execute this file against my localhost, `mysql-pymysql` database?
3. Do you have any recommendations to better outline these tables?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious why you have some columns specified as `Integer` and some as `Integer()`.  I think you only need to specify `Integer` and you can leave off the parens.  The foreign key looks alright to me.

To set this file up with your database, you'll need to use Python to run the file on your server, which will initialize it (provided you have the proper `import`s and other statements in the file in addition to these table definitions).  Then you can run whichever other Python file connects to it and adds the data in.